# Google Chrome edit bookmark dialog hangs the browser on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome, freeze

Opening of Google Chrome (stable) **Edit bookmark** dialog HANGS the browser - the browser starts to use 100% of CPU and its window slightly moves left/right. The process must be killed - it does not help to wait. It is reproducible on Chrome version `121.0.6167.160-1`, however, when I downgraded to version `120.0.6099.216-1` it works just fine

I switched off hardware acceleration (did not help). I use Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS, Gnome 3.36.8, X11.

Any idea what could be the cause?

Comment: Can you backtrace the process that is 100% CPU? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Backtrace#Already_running_programs